# Expected no. of tosses before getting a sequence of 'x' heads and 'y' tails

Tags: combinations, expectation

Recently I've been solving questions like "expected no. of trials before getting a particular sequence". The elegance of some of the solutions made me wonder whaich questions are solvable and which aren't.

Then I thought about this one: what would be the expected number of trials before getting a sequence of n heads followed by n tails?

In general, if you have two integers, x and y, what are the expected number of tosses before getting x continuous heads followed by y continuous tails?

I'm not sure if this is solvable for a general x and y. But x=y=n seems more solvable than the former.

My approach: 
Suppose A = expected no. of tosses to get x continuous heads, and B = expected no. of tosses before getting y continuous tails.

Let P = probability of getting y continuous tails. 
Then A/P should give us the expected no. of tosses before getting x heads and y tails.

Justification: Lets say there are n experiments, out of which k times you get y continuous tails.

Now suppose you keep tossing coins to get 'x' continuous heads, for which you will do 'A' coin tosses. The moment you get 'x' continuous heads, you continue tossing coins for 'y' continuous tails.

Suppose the event of tossing coins 'A' times is conducted n number of times. Then out of them, k events will also give you y consecutive tails after x consecutive heads. So on an average, after every n/k no. of such events you will have one such (x,y) event i.e. an event with x continuous heads and y continuous tails.

Not sure of the answer, haven't seen this question anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Fix positive integers $x,y$.

For $0 \le m \le x+y$, let $e(m)$ be the expected number of tosses required to get an $H,\!T$-sequence of length $x+y$, comprised of $x$ heads, followed by $y$ tails, assuming the $m$ immediately preceding prior tosses match the initial $m$ terms of the target sequence.

Then for $0\le m \le x+y$, we get
$$
e(m)=
\begin{cases}
0&\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,m=x+y\\[4pt]
1+(\frac{1}{2})\,e(m+1)+(\frac{1}{2})\,e(0)&\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,0 \le m < x\\[4pt]
1+(\frac{1}{2})\,e(x+1)+(\frac{1}{2})\,e(x)&\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,m=x\\[4pt]
1+(\frac{1}{2})\,e(m+1)+(\frac{1}{2})\,e(1)&\;\;\;\text{if}\;\,x < m < x+y\\
\end{cases}
$$
which yields a system of $x+y+1$ linear equations, in $x+y+1$ unknowns.

Solving the system for $e(0)$, test data strongly suggests (but I don't have a proof) that the expected number of tosses required to get an $H,\!T$-sequence of length $x+y$, comprised of $x$ heads, followed by $y$ tails, is $2^{x+y}$.

**Update:**

The OP has now provided a link to a web article:

$\qquad$[randomprojection] -- Martingales & Coins - Waiting for Heads-Tails-Heads (2012)

$\qquad$https://tsourakakis.com/2012/01/01/waiting-for-heads-tails-heads/

which provides three different approaches for dealing with these kinds of problems.

The second approach is quite novel, and shows how to interpret the problem as a martingale.

Following that approach, the result $e(0)=2^{x+y}$ is immediate.

In particular, if $x=y=n$, we get $e(0)=4^n$.

Comment: Can this also be done using Martingale?By modelling it as gamblers betting on the occurrence of the sequence by betting a dollar on every toss and a new gambler being added after every toss, and then Using E[Xi - i] = 0, where Xi = total money all gamblers have after i tosses and i = no. of tosses until the sequence occurs

Comment: I don't really follow your construction, but any valid model needs to somehow be equivalent to the system of equations I specified.

Comment: Check this out: https://tsourakakis.com/2012/01/01/waiting-for-heads-tails-heads/

Comment: Interesting article. When I get a chance, I'll see if I can apply some of those ideas.

Comment: By applying the idea from that link, I get simply 4^n. Also, for x=y=2, I get expected no. of tosses as 16. Your answer doesn't seem to match.

Comment: Yes, after correcting my equations, I also get $4^n$. I've edited my answer accordingly, and included a link to the reference you provided..

Comment: @qwerty_uiop: for martingale approach to this sort of problems try to google "ABRACADABRA" problem from the book by David Williams , "Probability with martingales" (a problem about a monkey typing random letters from A-Z and waiting to get a certain string) . There is indeed an astonishingly beautiful approach by martingales (google will lead you there)

Comment: I don't have an EECS/IEOR background so understanding very complex concepts baed on other concepts is difficult. Experienced that when trying to understand Martingales using sigma algebra etc. In this link, https://tsourakakis.com/2012/01/01/waiting-for-heads-tails-heads/, what is the reason for the E[P] i.e. the expected value of the profit for the casino to be zero? I am not able to get an intuitive idea of why that should be the case, or come up with an argument/proof for that. That is the author's base assumption upon which everything is based.

Comment: @qwerty_uiop: Every bet has expected value zero for the player (and for the house), and expectations add, so the house has expected value zero against _any_ sequence of zero expectation bets.